# GAE with JPA and REST: Produce Entity (as json or xml) with the datastore.Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Article {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key key;
private String content;
private String title;
private Date created; 
private Date lastUpdate;

private boolean isActive;

   /* public getter and setters */
}
```

Now I have a rest webserivce which returns the articles:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@GET
@Path("/{user}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<Article> getArtilceListByUser(@PathParam("user") String userName) {

    List<Article> articles = null;
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        articles = (List<Article>) em.createQuery("SELECT FROM Article WHERE createdBy = :user AND isActive = true")
                    .setParameter("user", userName)
                    .getResultList();
        // lazy load is activated, but em is closed (find a better solution)
        for (Article article : articles) ;

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return articles;
}
```

The problem is, that the object of *com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key* cannot get serialized to json or xml, but I need the id of the articles... So have I to use a long-type for the id or to add an extra field, which wraps the key? Do you have better solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.keyToString

and then

com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.stringToKey

These create and consume "websafe" keys for just this purpose.

Comment: It is not the problem to get the Id as a string, it is a problem to marshal the key as json or xml. So I am looking for right pattern to produce my entity in json or xml **with** the id.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Once the key is a string it's easy to serialize it... there are many tools/frameworks for serializing json. We use Jersey (http://jersey.java.net/) which is a jax-rs compliant framework. That may be too heavyweight for your needs but it's pretty simple to use. A lot of folks use resteasy as well: http://www.jboss.org/resteasy

Comment: This is not my question. I was just looking for a good pattern. So do you mean I should just add a getter-method which just returns the id?

Comment: You could write a getter method that makes the KeyFactory.keyToString() call and make sure that your json serializer is calling that instead of the getKey() method. Definitely don't create a setter method there though. You may find it easier to create a DTO object that's getting serialized instead of the actual Article class. Alternatively you could write a custom serialization handler for the object and wire that into whatever you are using for json serialization (looks like jersey perhaps?)

Comment: Sorry, hit return too soon. I would also suggest as an option to look at using Objectify for your data access tier. Objectify hides the AppEngine Key object from you and lets you use a string or long instead as your primary key. That makes this entire problem go away :-)

Comment: Wow, Objectify is great lib, so I'll use this :) Thank you for you help!